# Filtrado de fecha typescipt y javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Estoy realizando un filtro de fechas, pero cuando hago la consulta, no me la trae y en su caso, me carga vacio o 0.

En la base de datos está la hora como **T04,T02,T06** y por ende no consulta.

He tratado de arreglarlo de varias maneras, pero aún nada.

```
      
let fch2 = moment(`${y}-${m}-${4}`).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // formato de fecha manual
let fp2 = new Date(fch2 + "T00:00:00.000Z"); // formato de date
         
let d4 = _.filter(client, { fechaVenta: fp2, usern: uid }).length; //filtra los datos
let vd4;

if (d4 !== 0) {
  vd4 = d4;
} else {
  vd4 = 0;
}
console.log(fch2, fp2, d4 )
```